# How to mark with bullets on some specific points in a cartesian plance in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, lattice

I am drawing a lattice (vector space) as follows:

[image]

using the following tikz code

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[ultra thick,->] (0,0) -- (9,0) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
        \draw[ultra thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,9) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};
        \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9}
        \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
        \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
        \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (8,8);
        \draw[->, ultra thick, blue](0,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[->, ultra thick, red](0,0) -- (0,1);
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=3pt,fill] at (1,4) {};
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (0,2) {};
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (0,6) {};
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (6,0) {};
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (2,0) {};
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (2,4) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

Why is the only point (1,4) plotted? Why are not other points (0,2), (0,6),... plotted?

I think I am missing the right syntax in the last 6 lines of the code.

**Edit:** I solved it

Comment: All points are rendered, but you set `inner sep=1pt` (except for the first one) which renders them quite small, so they're hard to spot. By the way, `\large` does not do anything here. It only would, if you put some text after it, but you want empty nodes, I guess. Hint: `\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` can be simpler typed as `\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, if i don't put `\large`, an error comes `failed to get a list of font size`

Comment: @JasperHabicht, it solved. I just need to put a bracket `{}` after every node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You put the grid line as the first line inside \tikzpicture environnement, all points are visibles. Better if the color of grid lines is gray!20, for example.

Output:

[image]

**ADD** to answer to Zarko comment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (8,8);
        \draw[ultra thick,->] (0,0) -- (9,0) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
        \draw[ultra thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,9) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};
        \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
        \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
        \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
        \draw[->, ultra thick, blue](0,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[->, ultra thick, red](0,0) -- (0,1);
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=3pt,fill] at (1,4) {};
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (0,2) {};
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (0,6) {};
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (6,0) {};
        \node[green,draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (2,0) {};
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (2,4) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. How to change the color of the bullet points from black to other color

Comment: Is it possible to include all nodes using only one command `\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (2,0) {};` instead  of several same commands as in my question ?

Comment: For the first question: Yes. You can choose the color,for example You write \node[red,draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (2,4) {};.
For the second question yes and no: Yes if all dots have the sames properties (size, color,...). No if You want different properties.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You can also accept my answer, if You like...

Comment: Where is MWE, which produce showed image?

Answer (score 1):

- Mostly of topic, since your code fragment produce desired image, but code for dots /circles are inconsistent, see @learner comment.
- Please, always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document, which we can compile as it is and which rešroduce your problem.
- I would draw your image on the following way:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
arr/.style = {color=#1, very thick, -Stealth},
arr/.default = black,
dot/.style = {circle, fill=#1, inner sep=2pt, node contents={}}
                        ]
% axis
\draw[arr] (0,0) -- (9,0) node[below=1pt] {x axis};
\draw[arr] (0,0) -- (0,9) node[ left=1pt] {y axis};
% tick
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,8}
{
\draw (\i,1mm) -- ++ (0,-2mm) node[below] {\i};
\draw (1mm,\i) -- ++ (-2mm,0) node[left] {\i};
}
% unit vectors,
\draw[arr=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[arr= red] (0,0) -- (0,1);
% grid
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (8,8);
% dots
\path   (0,2) node[dot=cyan]
        (1,4) node[dot=purple]
        (2,4) node[dot=black]
        (0,6) node[dot=teal];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** added missing dot.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks